# How large would the earth have to be to retain hydrogen?

Tags: atmospheric-science, earth

How high would the earth's escape velocity  have to be to retain hydrogen or helium over geological timescales?

Comment: [What is the minimum planetary mass to hold an atmosphere over geologic time?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/what-is-the-minimum-planetary-mass-to-hold-an-atmosphere-over-geologic-time-scal)

Answer (score 3):

You can never fully retain any gas in a gravitational field as the statistical velocity distribution means that some gas atoms will have a velocity exceeding the escape velocity (mind you, hydrogen is even escaping from the Sun in form of the solar wind).

The mean thermal velocity of (moleculer) hydrogen atoms at a temperature of 300K is actually only 1.6 km/sec, considerably less than the escape velocity of 11 km/sec. But according to the Maxwell distribution function, a small number of molecules will have a velocity high enough to escape. Even hydrogen molecules with lower speed will have enough energy though to reach a height of a couple of 100km. The point is that at these heights they become dissociated into atomic hydrogen by the intense UV radiation, gaining energy in the process (the temperature at these heights is 1000-2000K). With the mass now also smaller, they have then a much higher velocity and escape more easily.

Having said this, the Earth has retained of course a lot of hydrogen in the form of water. It is only in its bare form that it tends to escape.